# Cambiar un avatar creado con advanced custom fields desde el frontend

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Uso la ùltima versión pro de ACF. Con este le he asignado una imagen como avatar que luego se ve en el custom-profiole-template que he hecho. 
Mi problema es que este avatar debe poderse cambiar desde el mismo frontend adjuntando una imagen nueva y eliminado la antigua, y no tengo ni idea como hacer que lo haga. Me he mirado la documentación de ACF como 60 veces y al final llego a la misma vía muerta
De momento esto esta así

```
<form>
     <div id="img-logo"><?php echo get_avatar( $current_user->ID ); ?></div>

           <div id="inputfile">
                <input type="file" name="file">
                <input type="submit" for="file">
           </div> 
 </form>
```

Se que no es mucho, pero es que no se como hacer, he probado con acf_form custom array, pero tampoco llego a buen puerto.
Alguien me puede ayudar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bueno lo primero que tienes que hacer es que tu formulario realice la carga del archivo a tu wordpress. Puedes trabajar con la función `wp_handle_upload`

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_handle_upload

Esta función subirá tu imagen, creara el post en la base de datos y te responderá con la URL de la imagen y su ID. Necesitas enviarle el archivo como parámetro.

```
function addImage($file){

    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/admin.php' );

      $file_return = wp_handle_upload( $file, array('test_form' => false ) );

      if( isset( $file_return['error'] ) || isset( $file_return['upload_error_handler'] ) ) {
          return false;
      } else {

          $filename = $file_return['file'];

          $attachment = array(
              'post_mime_type' => $file_return['type'],
              'post_title' => preg_replace( '/\.[^.]+$/', '', basename( $filename ) ),
              'post_content' => '',
              'post_status' => 'inherit',
              'guid' => $file_return['url']
          );

          $attachment_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $file_return['url'] );

          require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php');
          $attachment_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attachment_id, $filename );
          wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attachment_id, $attachment_data );

          if( 0 < intval( $attachment_id ) ) {

            $response = [
              'ID' => $attachment_id,
              'url' => $file_return['url']
            ];

            return $response;
          }
      }

      return false;
    }
```

Cuando el archivo suba puedes realizar la actualización del ACF con la URL del avatar y en el ID del usuario el cual puedes obtener con la función `get_current_user_id()`

Espero te funcione.